# Sort by weight using \Drupal::entityQuery()

Tags: 8, database

I want to get all taxonomy term in `$lang` language, following snippet works correctly and return all terms of `$lang` code.

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');
    $query->condition('vid', "news_category");
    $query->condition('langcode', $lang);
    $tids = $query->execute();
    //$terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($tids);
    return new JsonResponse($tids);
```

Then I want get results in order that in the taxonomy list they are, try to sort them with `$query->sort('weight','ASC');` but with following snippet the results are  the same before adding sort.

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');
    $query->condition('vid', "news_category");
    $query->condition('langcode', $lang);
    $query->sort('weight','ASC');
    $tids = $query->execute();
    //$terms = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::loadMultiple($tids);
    return new JsonResponse($tids);
```

Does anybody know where the problem is? How can I get terms in order they are in  taxonomy list?

Answer (score 5):

Taxonomy overview list uses something like:

```
  ->sort('weight', 'ASC')
  ->sort('name', 'ASC')
```

If that doesn't work for you, take a look at `\Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage::loadTree`

Comment: thansk for your attention, but not worked

Comment: in my question I write down sort by weight, adding another sort by name couldn't help. **This is not WORKS**

Comment: I confirm that it works for a flat list only.

Answer (score 3):

As was previously suggested, taking a look at `\Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage::loadTree` is helpful. Entity Query only provides access to properties of the entity and its Field API values. Since the weight of the term is available in the `taxonomy_term_field_data` table, it will be available to entityQuery as well. However, any nesting of terms, aka hierarchy, will require access to the `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` table. That would require a database query.

You can access it via a database query, as seen in `loadTree`, line 204:

```
    $query = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_term_field_data', 't');
    $query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'h', 'h.tid = t.tid');
    $result = $query
      ->addTag('taxonomy_term_access')
      ->fields('t')
      ->fields('h', array('parent'))
      ->condition('t.vid', $vid)
      ->condition('t.default_langcode', 1)
      ->orderBy('t.weight')
      ->orderBy('t.name')
      ->execute();
```

I have updated the query to use Drupal's container, rather than the dependency injection so it can be used more readily. You should be able to modify this to fit your needs if Entity Query is not working as you desire it to.